# Encrypting with AES using sha256 password

Tags: python, encryption

I'm trying to implement Shamir Secret Sharing Sceme in python,i need to ask the user for a password and then obtain a hash code with sha256, but when I try  to use that as a parameter for AES it says that the length of the key must be 16, 24 or 32 bits, doesn´t sha256 return a 32  byte string?

Here's my code:

```
import getpass
import hashlib
import random
import operator
from functools import reduce
import sys
import os
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

p= 208351617316091241234326746312124448251235562226470491514186331217050270460481
points= []

## Class Prime
#
# Class that represents integers modulo p, it is built from a non negative integer
# , comes with its own implementations of basic operations like sum, multiplication
# and division, the division is calculated ith the extended euclidean algorithm.
class Prime(object):
    ## The constructor
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n % p
    def __add__(self, other): return Prime(self.n + other.n)
    def __sub__(self, other): return Prime(self.n - other.n)
    def __mul__(self, other): return Prime(self.n * other.n)
    def __pow__(self, x): return Prime(self.n**x)
    def __truediv__(self, other): return self * other.inverse()
    def __div__(self, other): return self * other.inverse()
    def __neg__(self): return Prime(-self.n)
    def __eq__(self, other): return isinstance(other, Prime) and self.n == other.n
    def __abs__(self): return abs(self.n)
    def __str__(self): return str(self.n)
    def __divmod__(self, divisor):
        q,r = divmod(self.n, divisor.n)
        return (Prime(q), Prime(r))
    def EuclideanAlgorithm(a, b):
        if abs(b) > abs(a):
            (x,y,d) = EuclideanAlgorithm(b, a)
            return (y,x,d)
        if abs(b) == 0:
            return (1, 0, a)
        x1, x2, y1, y2 = 0, 1, 1, 0
        while abs(b) > 0:
            q, r = divmod(a,b)
            x = x2 - q*x1
            y = y2 - q*y1
            a, b, x2, x1, y2, y1 = b, r, x1, x, y1, y
        return (x2, y2, a)
    def inverse(self):
        (x,y,d)= EuclideanAlgorithm(self.n, p)
        return Prime(x)

## Class Polynomial
#
# Class that represents a polynomial, it is built from a list of coefficients
# comes with a call method to evaluate the polynomial in a value "x", and has
# a reduced lagrange method that gets the constant value of a polynomial from
# a set of points
class Polynomial(object):
    ## The constructor
    def __init__(self, coefficients):
        self.coeff= coefficients
    def __call__(self, x):
        n = 0
        tmp = Prime(0)
        for i in self.coeff:
            tmp = tmp + (i*(x**n))
            n += 1
        return tmp
    def lagrange(points):
        product= functools.reduce(operator.mul, points, 1)
        sum= 0
        for x in points:
            p= 1
            for y in points:
                if x!= y:
                    p= p*(x-y)
            sum+= poly(x)/(-x*p)
        return sum

## Ask the user for a password and gets its hash code with sha256
def password():
    p= getpass.getpass()
    h= hashlib.sha256(p)
    s= h.hexdigest()
    constant= int(s, 16)
    return constant

## Makes a polynomial with random coefficients and a fixed constant value, and
# evaluates it with n random values an writes the results to a file.
# @param constant The constant value of the polynomial.
# @param evaluations The number of evaluations to be made.
# @param degree The degree of the polynomial.
# @param out_fileName The name of the file where the evaluations are going
# to be written.
# \pre The constant, evaluations and degree must be positive integers.
# \post If no error occurs then, the file whose name was passed will contain
# n evaluations of the polynomial.
def makeKeys(constant, evaluations, degree, out_fileName):
    coeffs= []
    coeffs.append(Prime(constant))
    for x in range(1, degree):
        randomc= random.randint(1, p - 1)
        coeffs.append(Prime(randomc))
    poly= Polynomial(coeffs)
    file= open(out_fileName, "w")
    for x in range(1, evaluations + 1):
        randomi= random.randint(1, p - 1)
        points.append(randomi)
        e= poly(Prime(randomi))
        file.write("(%d, %d)\n" % (randomi, e.n))
    file.close()

def encrypt(key, in_fileName, out_fileName):
    iv = ''.join(chr(random.randint(0, 0xFF)) for i in range(16))
    encryptor = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_ECB, iv)
    filesize = os.path.getsize(in_filename)
    with open(in_filename, 'rb') as infile:
        with open(out_filename, 'wb') as outfile:
            outfile.write(struct.pack('<Q', filesize))
            outfile.write(iv)
            while True:
                chunk = infile.read(chunksize)
                if len(chunk) == 0:
                    break
                elif len(chunk) % 16 != 0:
                    chunk += ' ' * (16 - len(chunk) % 16)
                outfile.write(encryptor.encrypt(chunk))

def decrypt(ciphertext, key):
    iv = ciphertext[:AES.block_size]
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_ECB, iv)
    plaintext = cipher.decrypt(ciphertext[AES.block_size:])
    return plaintext.rstrip(b"\0")

def decrypt_file(file_name, key):
    with open(file_name, 'rb') as fo:
        ciphertext = fo.read()
    dec = decrypt(ciphertext, key)
    with open(file_name[:-4], 'wb') as fo:
        fo.write(dec)
```

Comment: Your example is too big to be able to understand. Please provide a minimal one to get answers. Eg. just call get password function and the AES one.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see the link between pasword and encrypt/decrypt functions but I supose password returns the key. In this case the key is an int that has 32 or 64 bits. Minimum for AES is 128 bits.

Try this:

```
def password(): 
   p= getpass.getpass() 
   h= hashlib.sha256(p) 
   return h.digest()
```

Comment: That doesn´t work, because i need to convert that password to an integer modulo prime, for the polynomial

Comment: Ok. Then if you are using python 2 modify your original code to use long instead of int

Comment: Isn't h.digest() a string?

Comment: Yes it is. Your main problem is that AES wants binary key (a string in pyton 2) while your Prime class wants an int. Use struct.pack and struct.unpack to convert between formats.

Comment: What?  AES minimum key size is 128 bits... Not bytes... Was that a typo in the last line or...?

Comment: Yes, it is 128 bits.